# Disease on peach fruit

Tags: identification, diagnosis, fruit-trees, diseases

Are the pink spots on this peach flesh some sort of disease? I got these from family who bought them at a farm stand in CO. The first one I ate had normal flesh, but the next two have looked like this. (As an aside, I would definitely say they're overripe and I did taste them and they don't taste good.)

[image: pink spotted peach flesh]
[image: more peaches]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's over ripening after having been kept in cold storage. Or it's frost damage while still on the tree. Either way the outside can look fine but the inside is decomposing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure this isn't a disease, but just the way the variety grows. I have bought a few of these kind of peaches this season. I think it's the first time I've seen those red streaks in the peach flesh, but the ones I got were wonderful and delicious. So not all peaches that look like that are overripe & bad tasting.

There are so many different varieties of peaches, and I think they're coming up with new ones all the time. There are bound to be types we haven't seen before. Maybe this red-streak variety is new, or newly-popular, or maybe you and I have just missed seeing it all this time, but I really doubt it is a disease.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I've had several peaches like this over the years from different varieties and not all of the same variety have this discoloration, so I don't think that it's based on the variety. Every time I see these spots/streaks on the flesh itself, the peach is bland tasting and often has an unpleasant texture. Peaches from the same box that do not have the discoloration are delicious. I've never been able to find out what the discoloration is, so I was curious if anyone knew!

Comment: Possibly some sort of stress has made the fruit do this- not a disease or problem as such- impossible to tell what has done this, all you can do is make sure the tree is happy- mulched, feed and watered, protect from frost and pests etc and good luck for next year.